# URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed

Tags: debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Problem: facebook like button does not work well for language sub-directories, but works for the root site.

```
http://secure.miamibeach411.com/tour-of-miami.html - works properly.
http://secure.miamibeach411.com/de/tour-of-miami.html - does not work.
```

Actually, the sub-directories are virtual and all requests are handled by the same files.

The debugger says the redirects could not be followed for some reason.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsecure.miamibeach411.com%2Fde%2Ftour-of-miami.html

Please assist.

UPDATE:

The relative redirect has been fixed, but the issue remains.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your page redirects multiple times (aargh), and somewhere in there you have a location header like this:

```
Location: /de//product.php?productid=16133
```

Apart from the double `/` that should not be there, a Location header **requires** an absolute URL by definition.

(Most people don’t care about that and dismiss hints to that fact with *“yeah, but it works in every browser I tested, so what?”* – until they encounter a client that does not want to accept it [like here]. So that’s why I always say, if you’re alerted to that fact, fix this *error* right there and then.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I removed the relative redirect as well as the double slash. That was an obvious bug. Sorry, I had to notice it myself. However, it did not do a trick: the issue remains. Could you please let me know if there is another issue? I know about multiple redirects but this cannot be changed for certain reasons.